# How can I alter this column so Pandas will recognize it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with a csv that lists citations issued by a local city to residents who violated a homesharing law. One of the columns has the addresses of the violators. I added another column with the census tracts that those addresses are located in, but pandas is not recognizing it for some reason.

For example, one of the census tracts that appears multiple times in the census_tract column is 7002.00. But when I enter

```
citations[citations.census_tract == '7002.00']
```

All I get are the column headers with 0 rows.

But when I enter:

```
citations.census_tract
```

I get an accurate list of the census tracts in the census_tract column

What should I do to the column so pandas will read it when I try to get an output == to a specific census tract?

Comment: Can you add some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and expected output? If there are float like mentioned @anki_91 in answer it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to filter a float value but filter is a string in your input,

change:

`citations[citations.census_tract == '7002.00']`

to :

```
citations[citations.census_tract == 7002.00]
```

Another method as suggested by @jezrael using [`np.isclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
np.isclose(citations.census_tract,7002.00)
```

This will return a array of boolean based on condition matches.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that values from *census_tract* column have been read as *float*.
If this is what you intend then change the instruction in question to:

```
citations[citations.census_tract == 7002.00]
```

(without apostrophes).

Another possibility is that this column contains values only "looking like" *float*,
but actually they should be treated as **strings**.

If this is the case, read the *csv* file with respective parameter concerning
the type of this column. Something like:

```
types_dict = {'census_tract': string}
citations = read_csv('input.csv', dtype=types_dict)
```

Then your instruction should execute withot error.

The second version of your instruction (*citations[citations.census_tract]*)
is wrong, because:

- *pandas* reads values from *census_tract* column,
- looks in *citations* for **columns** with names just read.